# Register Page won't render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on a simple validation form using NodeJS, the problem is register.ejs won't render, I tried modifying the paths, changing the default folder but it still won't work, I'm new to Express and Node so a detailed explanation would be much appreciated, or any kind of explanation. Thank You

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
let path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'client');
app.use(express.static('client'))

app.get('', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
});

app.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('register')
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/userinfo.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Main page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
          <h1>Logo</h1>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-items">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="./courses/courses.html">Courses</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="./register/register">Register</a>
          </li>
          <div class="button">
            <button>Try Pro for Free!</button>
          </div>
        </ul>
        <div class="icons">
          <div class="bell-notif">
            <span class="badge"></span>
            <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
          <div class="line line1"></div>
          <div class="line line2"></div>
          <div class="line line3"></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div>
        <section class="user-info">
          <div class="user">
            <img
              alt="user-image"
              class="user-image"
            />
            <button class="edit-btn">Edit</button>
            <span class="username">
            </span>
            <span class="user-status">Premium Member</span>
          </div>
          <div class="streak">
            <h3 class="streak-days"></h3>
            <p class="streak-text"></p>
          </div>
          </section>
        </div>
<script src="./scripts/main.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/userinfo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

register.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/register.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Register</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
          <h1>Logo</h1>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-items">
            <!--class={!open ? "list-items" : "list-items active"}-->
          <li>
            <a href="../index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="../courses/courses.html">Courses</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="./register/register.ejs">Register</a>
          </li>
          <div class="button">
            <button>Try Pro for Free!</button>
          </div>
        </ul>
        <div class="icons">
          <div class="bell-notif">
            <span class="badge"></span>
            <i class="fa fa-bell bell"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
          <div class="line line1"></div>
          <div class="line line2"></div>
          <div class="line line3"></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    <div class="login-container">
      <form class="form">
        <h1 class="login-heading">Register to support us</h1>
        <br />
        <div class="inputfield">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="username-field" />
          <p class="error error-username">{Error here}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="inputfield">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="email-field" />
        </div>
        <p class="error error-email">{Error here}</p>
        <div class="inputfield">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="password-field" />
          <p class="error error-password">{Error here}</p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="submit-button">
          <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
          <br />
          <br />
          <span> Don't have an account? <a href="#">Register now!</a> </span>
          <br />
          <span>Or log in with:</span>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="login-icons">
          <i class="fa fa-google icon google"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-github icon github"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-linkedin icon linked-in"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-twitter icon twitter"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-facebook icon facebook"></i>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span class="password-forgot">
          Forgot your password? <br />
          <a href="#">Click here</a>
        </span>
      </form>
    </div>
  <script src="../scripts/register_validation.js"></script>
  <script src="../scripts/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Folder Structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

I just had to take a look at the address the hyperlink was pointing to in index.ejs
and add the slashes i forgot to add

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
let path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'client');
app.use(express.static('client'))


app.get('', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
});

app.get('/register/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('./register/register')
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```